# Upgrade PHP version 5.6 -> 7 issues on Linux

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Maybe its an old question, but i have some difficulties installing php 7 on my ubuntu environment. Right now I have ubuntu 15.10 and this is php version:

```
PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

I tried this method to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

and this was the result:

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpp_pz87v9/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpp_pz87v9/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpp_pz87v9/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

afther I executed this: `sudo apt-get update` and then:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

and the result of the last command is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
```

I have no idea what should I do next ? can you help me? thx

Comment: Please check this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7

Comment: Did the `update` run successfully?

Comment: yes, the update is successfull

Comment: @S.I. I already tried. and the result is the same

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [php version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.4) you posted, you are running Ubuntu 15.10, which is EOL (end of life). This means it's no longer supported. In addition, Ondřej Surý's repo for php does not support 15.10. Thus, when you run apt-get, it will not find the package, because it is not compatible with your Ubuntu version.

The solution I suggest is upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; you will receive support until 2021, and installing php7 using that command will work.